# $scope not updated - controller specification

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have the following routing:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',

    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/panel', {
                templateUrl: 'views/panel.html'
            }).
            when('/make', {
                templateUrl: 'views/makePanel.html',
                controller: 'painelCtrl'
            }).
            when('/paneluser', {

                templateUrl: 'views/panelUser.html',
                controller: 'userCtrl'

            }).
            when('/paneluserblocks', {
                templateUrl: 'views/userPanels.html',
                controller: 'userCtrl'
            }).
            when('/registred', {

                templateUrl: 'views/registredPanels.html'
            }).
             when('/color', {

                templateUrl: 'views/color.html',
                controller: 'alarmCtrl'
            }).
            otherwise('/', {
                templateUrl: 'Index.html',

            });
    }]);
```

When I specify a controller for a particular html template, my $scope variables are no longer updated in the view.

When I pull out the controller specification for a particular route, things return to normal.

The controller 'userCtrl' is accessed through $location and is intended for ordinary users. In turn, 'Ctrl panel' is the primary controller assigned to admin users.

Could anyone tell me what's going on?

Comment: are you initializing your scope variables when your routes gets changed? Can you create a demo replicating the issue

Comment: Yes. All variables by default are initialized with null value. The application is already very complex, I do not know if I could reproduce the problem in a demo.
The strange thing is that in the case of the controller 'alarmCtrl', everything happens well. I do not understand why other controllers are not working.
Variable values are updated via AJAX calls. I was able to see this through console.log (), but the same is not reflected in the view.

Comment: I understand you feel your code is complex, but you should really supply [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I will try to reproduce the effect in a small example code. Please, give me a few minutes ...

Comment: My friend, I'm coming to the conclusion that reproducing this problem is going to be complex. Everything works fine using only a single controller, but this is impractical.
Could you make a short video and make it available so you can take a look?

Comment: I was able to identify the problem.
When I do:
  TemplateUrl: 'views / panelUser.html',
   Controller: 'userCtrl'
Angular reinitializes all my variables present in 'userCtrl' and loses the reference of its contents. The solution would be to save the context of the $ scope variables in some way.
Would you know how to do this? Maybe a service or factory ... You would need an example.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't all information, but it's working in my demo.

**Config**

```
var app = angular.module('app',['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider',

    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/panel', {
                templateUrl: 'views/panel.html'
            }).
            when('/make', {
                templateUrl: 'views/makePanel.html',
                controller: 'painelCtrl'
            }).
            otherwise('/', {
                templateUrl: 'Index.html',

            });
    }]);
```

**Definition of your controller:**

```
app.controller('painelCtrl',painelCtrl);
painelCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'] //and more if you need $http, services, ...
function painelCtrl($scope){
     $scope.hello= "hello world"
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h1>{{hello}}</h1>
```

Comment: I was able to identify the problem.
When I do:
  TemplateUrl: 'views / panelUser.html',
   Controller: 'userCtrl'
Angular reinitializes all my variables present in 'userCtrl' and loses the reference of its contents. The solution would be to save the context of the $ scope variables in some way.
Would you know how to do this? Maybe a service or factory ... You would need an example.

Comment: When you change page the controller is reset. For store your data you have choice. Database, Factory / Service or sessionStorage /localStorage. Create init function and call your need inside. function init(){...} init();

Comment: Friend, look at the answer I posted and that solved my problem.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for the igenuidade. I believed that the pages being in the same controller, I would never miss the reference:

```
When ('/panel', {
                 TemplateUrl: 'views/panel.html',
    Controller: 'panelCtrl'
             }).
             When ('/make', {
                 TemplateUrl: 'views/makePanel.html',
            Controller: 'panelCtrl'
             }). cotinue...
```

In fact, views panel.html and makePanel.html will use the same controller structure, however we will have one instance for each view (variables will be reseted).
In my case I used factory functions to solve the problem. Every time I mute controller, I store the information of interest through a set () and get it through a get ();

```
app.factory("MonitorService", function () {
    var info;
    function set(data) {
        info = data;
    }
    function get() {
        return info;
    }
    return {
        set: set,
        get: get
    }

});
```